# Difference between Silverlight and WPF for TextBlock.BaselineOffset

Tags: wpf, silverlight, textblock

I'm using a shared code to produce documents in Silverlight and WPF. But the output is different for the TextBlock alignment.
For example for a TextBlock of height 100, displaying a text in Arial with a FontSize of 100 :

- In WPF the BaselineOffset is 92.16333
- In Silverlight the BaselineOffset is 90.52667

This difference depends on the font family, for example if I replace Arial by Times New Roman :

- In WPF the BaselineOffset is 91.23666
- In Silverlight the BaselineOffset is 89,11

Is there a way to correct this behaviour and have the same alignment in WPF and Silverlight ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Having worked in both WPF and Silverlight, I can confirm the rendering output of the same fonts at the same font size the output looks significantly different on screen.

In WPF you have a bit more control using [RenderOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) i.e.:

```html
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(tb, BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor);
RenderOptions.SetClearTypeHint(tb, ClearTypeHint.Auto);
RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(tb, EdgeMode.Aliased);
```

You may need to play with values above to get as close as possible. Also as the renderoptions API is WPF only, if you're in a shared codebase you'd need to wrap it in a #if WPF directive..

Comment: Thanks a lot for your idea. Unfortunately I've tried all the existing RenderOptions and no one is affecting the text alignment.